# Regex - stripping the first number or number and ajoining letter

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm attempting to remove the house number from an address and have successfully managed to remove the numbers, but I am stuck with examples that include a letter with the number, i.e. **12a The Street**.

Here's my code:

```
var pattern = /\d+(?!.*\d)([^]*)/;

$('#myTextbox').change(function () {
   strExport = ($('#_myTextbox').val().match(pattern) || [, $('#myTextbox').val()])[1];
   $('#myTextbox2').val($.trim(strExport))
});
```

I did manage to get the Regex working to remove the 12a, but then I broke it for pure number examples.

```
var pattern = /\d+-?[a-zA-Z]+(?!.*\d)([^]*)/;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply removing all non-space characters at the start of the string? (Not all addresses match the format you've shown, but you do seem to be starting with the assumption that everything up to the first space is the "number", so wouldn't `/^([^\s]+)\s(.+)$/` do the trick to capture both the "number" and the street name?)

Comment: My address is `12(a) The Street`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be much simpler than that:

```
var str = $('#_myTextbox').val();//"12a The Street"
str = str.replace(/^\w+\s+/,'');//"The Street"
```

Or for fixed `number then optional letters` format, use this regex instead:

```
/^\d+[a-z]*\s+/
```

FYI:

- `\w` is a 'word character', equating to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\d` is a digit, equating to `[0-9]`